# Trying to capture integer data from Firebase into an array, and then sum all the elements

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to grab a bunch of integer values from `Firebase`, store them into an array, and then add all the elements.

I've tried using

```
let sum:Int = challengeList.reduce(0, +)
```

to get the sum of the elements in an array called challengeList, but the error I receive is "Ambiguous reference to member '+'"

```
func LoadPointsCompleted() {

        self.challengeList.removeAll()

        databaseReference = Database.database().reference()

        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        let refChallenges = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Challenges").child(userID!).queryOrdered(byChild: "Status").queryEqual(toValue: "Complete")

        refChallenges.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            //if the reference have some values
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

                //clearing the list
                self.challengeList.removeAll()



                //iterating through all the values
                for Challenges in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    //getting values
                    let challengeObject = Challenges.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let Points = challengeObject?["Points"] as! Int

                    //creating challenge object with model and fetched values
                    let challenge = pointsModel(Points: Points as Int?)

                    //appending it to list
                    self.challengeList.append(challenge)


                    let sum:Int = challengeList.reduce(0, +)
                }


            }



        }

        )}
```

// also using the following model

```
import Foundation

class pointsModel {

    var Points: Int?

    init(Points: Int?){

        self.Points = Points
    }
}
```

I can't get this to compile...

Comment: Use lowercase letters to start your variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `points` are always `Int`, there is no need to make it optional. Also you can use `struct` and then there is no need for creating own initializer, you get it for free

```
struct PointsModel {
    var points: Int
}
```

... note that *types* starts with big capital letter and *constants, variables, methods* with small capital letter

---

Then you can get it compiled by adding `points` property to sum, not the whole model

```
challengeList.reduce(0) {$0 + $1.points}
```

Comment: Thanks Robert... Tried the following:

let sum = challengeList.reduce(0, {$0.points + $1.Points})

it now says "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" with the + highlighted.